# Selecting points within a radius

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm building a map that searches from a user's location to find nearby dealers.

I'm having a little trouble understanding how to use variable in a sql statement.  I am making the location with javascript and then posting the coordinates to make the query with php.  My code is below

```
$sql = "SELECT dealer_name, phone, street_number, route, locality, administrative_area_level_1, postal_code, website, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".latitude."') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('".longitude."') ) + sin( radians('".latitude."') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM dealers WHERE distance < '".miles."' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

Here is where I assign my location variables

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
```

Comment: I'll be bak in the morning. Sorry for late response to answers if any

Comment: I hope you are NOT constructing your SQL query in javascript...

Comment: Well I'm gonna need some tuts for ajax then.

Answer (score 2):

What language?  You have tagged JavaScript, but like one of the comments mentioned.. I sure hope you aren't building the SQL in JavaScript.

You should be passing the parameters to the server side (maybe an AJAX call) and then depending on the language you are using, build the SQL query appropriately.

See the Java example: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/